# Sorting string by specific column

Tags: python, sorting

I need to sort a text file. The file contains lines, separated by a new line `'\n'`. 
Example input:

```
ATOM   1591  O5'   G A 958       5.497  -3.281   3.598  1.00 99.99           O  
ATOM   1592  C5'   G A 958       4.345  -3.184   2.781  1.00 99.99           C 
ATOM      1  P     C A 924     -12.106   6.485 -14.650  1.00 99.99           P  
ATOM      2  OP1   C A 924     -12.981   6.565 -15.850  1.00 99.99           O  
ATOM      3  OP2   C A 924     -10.829   7.256 -14.620  1.00 99.99           O 
ATOM    429 2H4    C A 947       1.295  -1.142  -0.764  1.00 99.99           H  
ATOM    430  P     G A 948      -2.886  -4.112   7.863  1.00 99.99           P
```

And I want to sort them by the 6th column (`958`, `924` etc.)

```
ATOM      1  P     C A 924     -12.106   6.485 -14.650  1.00 99.99           P  
ATOM      2  OP1   C A 924     -12.981   6.565 -15.850  1.00 99.99           O  
ATOM      3  OP2   C A 924     -10.829   7.256 -14.620  1.00 99.99           O 
ATOM    429 2H4    C A 947       1.295  -1.142  -0.764  1.00 99.99           H  
ATOM    430  P     G A 948      -2.886  -4.112   7.863  1.00 99.99           P  
ATOM   1591  O5'   G A 958       5.497  -3.281   3.598  1.00 99.99           O  
ATOM   1592  C5'   G A 958       4.345  -3.184   2.781  1.00 99.99           C
```

I've tried doing it this way:

```
splitted = pdb_data.splitlines()
sorted(splitted, key = lambda residue: int(residue.split()[5]))
pdb_data = '\n'.join(splitted)
pdb_data +='\nTER\n'
```

but it's not sorted. :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong method to sort; to sort *in place*, use the [`list.sort()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types):

```
splitted.sort(key = lambda residue: int(residue.split()[5]))
```

The [`sorted()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) returns a *new list*, leaving the original list unsorted, but your code ignores the return value.

You could also assign the return value of `sorted()` back to `splitted` but that'd be rather inefficient here.

Your sort itself works just fine:

```
>>> splitted = '''\
... ATOM   1591  O5'   G A 958       5.497  -3.281   3.598  1.00 99.99           O  
... ATOM   1592  C5'   G A 958       4.345  -3.184   2.781  1.00 99.99           C 
... ATOM      1  P     C A 924     -12.106   6.485 -14.650  1.00 99.99           P  
... ATOM      2  OP1   C A 924     -12.981   6.565 -15.850  1.00 99.99           O  
... ATOM      3  OP2   C A 924     -10.829   7.256 -14.620  1.00 99.99           O 
... ATOM    429 2H4    C A 947       1.295  -1.142  -0.764  1.00 99.99           H  
... ATOM    430  P     G A 948      -2.886  -4.112   7.863  1.00 99.99           P   
... '''.splitlines()
>>> splitted.sort(key = lambda residue: int(residue.split()[5]))
>>> pdb_data = '\n'.join(splitted)
>>> print pdb_data
ATOM      1  P     C A 924     -12.106   6.485 -14.650  1.00 99.99           P  
ATOM      2  OP1   C A 924     -12.981   6.565 -15.850  1.00 99.99           O  
ATOM      3  OP2   C A 924     -10.829   7.256 -14.620  1.00 99.99           O 
ATOM    429 2H4    C A 947       1.295  -1.142  -0.764  1.00 99.99           H  
ATOM    430  P     G A 948      -2.886  -4.112   7.863  1.00 99.99           P   
ATOM   1591  O5'   G A 958       5.497  -3.281   3.598  1.00 99.99           O  
ATOM   1592  C5'   G A 958       4.345  -3.184   2.781  1.00 99.99           C
```